# What do "transparent" and "opaque" mean when applied to programming concepts?

Tags: language-agnostic, terminology

The two pieces of programming jargon that cause me the most confusion are the words ***transparent*** and ***opaque***. They are fairly commonly used, but I have never been fully clear on their meaning.

Google throws up plenty of examples of usage of the word 'transparent', like:

- [Fast 'C' library to tranparently manage very large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091378/fast-c-library-to-tranparently-manage-very-large-files)
- [Saving application data transparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289268/saving-application-data-transparently)
- [Adding JSON Strings transparently to a map/list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16963693/adding-json-strings-transparently-to-a-map-list)
- [How do I use GNU Screen transparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501891/how-do-i-use-gnu-screen-transparently)

and also a bunch of results for 'opaque', mostly relating to C concepts:

- [What defines an opaque type in C, and when are they necessary and/or useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301454/what-defines-an-opaque-type-in-c-and-when-are-they-necessary-and-or-useful)
- [What is an opaque pointer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553750/what-is-an-opaque-pointer-in-c)
- [Opaque C structs: how should they be declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965279/opaque-c-structs-how-should-they-be-declared)

although I've also seen the word used in contexts unrelated to C.

Leaving aside their use within specific compound terms like "opaque pointer", what meanings do the words *transparent* and *opaque* have within the sphere of programming? Are they even each other's opposites, like the visual concepts they metaphorically allude to, or are they unrelated to each other?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In the examples you give, **transparent** is being used to mean *hidden* in the sense of things taking place automatically behind the scenes (i.e. without the user of the code or the program having to interact).

**Opaque** is also being used to mean *hidden*, which is perhaps where the confusion comes in. The term *opaque type* has a [specific meaning in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735131), where it refers to a type that has been declared but not yet defined.

In both cases, I think people are using these terms to express a lack of visibility. **Transparent** is used where something is present, but you can't see it. **Opaque** is used where something is present, but you can't see *inside* it to inspect its inner workings.

Comment: That may be the case, but I'd say that everyone who describes a hidden mechanism as transparent is using the word incorrectly and should really use the word opaque instead.

Comment: @Distortum **Transparent** means it’s invisible for the eyes of the observer. For example updates of a software system to happen w.o the end user notice it or a system that communicate with an api while this goes over a proxy. In this cases the update process and the proxy are transparent as they do not exist to the observer.

Comment: @kalitsov The problem is that usage of the word transparent is the opposite of how the word is normally used. E.g. Merriam-Webster defines transparent as: 1. readily understood 2. characterized by visibility or accessibility of information especially concerning business practices

Comment: Something that's present and you can't see is better described as *invisible* or *hidden*, not *transparent*. A glass jar is transparent but certainly not invisible. *Transparent* is the opposite of *opaque*, as in something you can see through versus something you can't (glass jar vs black box).

Comment: This is probably too nuanced, but the distinction I make is where visibility to the original intent ends. Example: if I call an API to provision a VM, the provisioning process is "opaque" to me because everything past the API call is a black box. I don't know how it works, and I have to trust it fulfills my intent. In contrast, let's say I have a telemetry library that publishes metrics when my service makes an API call. The telemetry is handled for me, without a change to my interface or behavior. My intent passes _through_ the telemetry library unchanged, hence transparent.

Comment: @Steve is right, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type